# Does anyone know how to bring this shrub back to life?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I live in Arizona and have this shrub in my front yard. I am unsure what exactly it is. Does anyone know how to bring it back so it fills out the dead sides?

Side 1:[image: side 1]

Side 2:[image: side 2]

Comment: I think if someone can identify the plant first, that the question can then be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that there is parts that are still alive.  I would begin trimming back the dead areas in small increments.  You will start to get to a point where the dead branches have some health to them.  They wont snap from being dead and dry but bend some.  Leave those and see if you start to get it to fill in.  It might take a season to fill in to your liking.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot.